# Change Type of Method Reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

My code:

```
class BlogPost {
    String title;
    String author;
    BlogPostType type;
    int likes;

    public BlogPost(String title, String author, BlogPostType type, int likes) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.type = type;
        this.likes = likes;
    }
//getter setter
}
```

and:

```
public enum BlogPostType {
    NEWS,
    REVIEW,
    GUIDE
}
```

and:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BlogPost> posts = Arrays.asList(new BlogPost("Start Java", "Ram", BlogPostType.NEWS, 11),
            new BlogPost("Start Java 8", "Rajou", BlogPostType.REVIEW, 101),
            new BlogPost("Functional programming", "Das", BlogPostType.REVIEW, 111),
            new BlogPost("Lambda", "Ramos", BlogPostType.GUIDE, 541));

        Map<BlogPostType, List<BlogPost>> Blist = posts.stream().collect(groupingBy(BlogPost::getType));
        System.out.println(Blist);
}}
```

I have three classes one is `BlogPost` , `BlogPostType` and `Main`.

I am making a map of `Map<BlogPostType, List<BlogPost>> Blist` by using `groupingBy()` and it works perfectly fine. i used a method reference there **BlogPost::getType** , i can use lambda expression also `(x) -> x.getType()`.

But when i try to change the type of Map , i.e `Map<String, List<BlogPost>> Blist1` then i cannot use **Method reference**. Is there any possible way to use method reference and get the type also changed??

I am thinking why cant we use like this: `BlogPost::getType.toString()` or `(String)BlogPost::getType` while we can do this in lambda `(x) -> x.getType().toString()`.
Any possible ways to use Method reference and get along with conversion of type also?

Comment: I don't believe you can get a method reference from a method reference, something like `BlogPost::getType::toString`. You need to use a function for that. Note that I find it better to use your enum as a key instead of a `String`.

Comment: Calling a `toString` method on any object is not converting the type! What you are trying to achieve does not exist. What's wrong with a lambda expression that does exactly what you want?

Comment: I wanna stick to method reference while the type also to be changed if possible with casting.

Comment: But ... why? There is nothing specific about method references, as I have written in my answer: they are just a shortcut for that lambda expression. Why do you want to force your readers to look at something that is **less** clear than a simply lambda that does a toString() call?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Function.identity()` to chain method references (as many as you want). For example, put the following function in `groupingBy`:

```
Function.<BlogPost>identity()
        .andThen(BlogPost::getType)
        .andThen(BlogPostType::toString)
```

**but it's better to use lambda**

Comment: Method chaining seems more understanding, though one should always prefer lambda whenever and whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

A method reference is **just** that: a "reference" to some specific method.

There is no implicit conversion or anything. Just a method that has a certain signature, and syntactic **shortcut** to express that without writing down a lambda expression.

If you want to use a method reference, that thing must exist as method. In other words, you would need to a *new* method like

```
String getTypeAsString()
```

to your `BlogPost` class. Only then you can go and directly invoke that method via a method reference.

But in your case, simply use that lambda expression instead that calls `toString()` explicitly. It sounds wrong to have a special method there that does "almost" the same as another method, just to enable you to write down a method reference.

Alternatively, follow the interesting approach pointed out in Eran's answer to use `andThen()`.

In the end, your focus should be to write code that is easy to read and understand for you and your team. My personal recommendation would be to use the lambda right there, as all other solutions just add a lot of noise for no real gain.

Answer (score 2):

> Method reference in place of lambda expression makes your code more
>   readable, hence it is advised to replace lambda expression with method
>   reference, **Whenever Possible**.

Remember a method reference replace a **single** method invocation , in your case `BlogPost::getType` will work fine while `BlogPost::getType.toString()` will not work as it is not single method invocation.

A method reference replace a single method invocation, so it can’t simply replace a lambda expression consisting of ***more than one method invocation***.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with two method references as follows, but I'd stick with the lambda expression, which is much simpler.

```
Map<String, List<BlogPost>> Blist = 
    posts.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(((Function<BlogPost,BlogPostType>)BlogPost::getType).andThen(BlogPostType::toString)));
```

or

```
Function<BlogPost,BlogPostType> getType = BlogPost::getType;
Map<String, List<BlogPost>> Blist = 
    posts.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(getType.andThen(BlogPostType::toString)));
```

Comment: @GhostCat yep, as I said, I'd stick with the lambda expression.